# Numpy Matrix class: Default constructor attributes for inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, numpy, init

I want to implement my own matrix-class that inherits from numpy's matrix class.

numpy's matrix constructor requires an attribute, something like `("1 2; 3 4'")`. In contrast, my constructor should require no attributes and should set a default attribute to the super-constructor.

That's what I did:

```py
import numpy as np

class MyMatrix(np.matrix):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMatrix, self).__init__("1 2; 3 4")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix = MyMatrix()
```

There must be a stupid mistake in this code since I keep getting this error:

```py
this_matrix = np.matrix()
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm really clueless about that and googling didn't help so far.

Thanks!

Comment: It is looking for the data.  Here is what I got definition from help
`__new__(subtype, data, dtype=None, copy=True)`

Comment: Yes, that are the arguments required to instantiate a numpy.matrix class. What I'm passing to the super-constructor `("1 2; 3 4")` is that `data`-attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!

From looking at the source, it seems as though `np.matrix` sets the `data` argument in [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), not in `__init__`. This is counterintuitive behaviour, though I'm sure there's a good reason for it.

Anyway, the following works for me:

```
class MyMatrix(np.matrix):
    def __new__(cls):
        # note that we have to send cls to super's __new__, even though we gave it to super already.
        # I think this is because __new__ is technically a staticmethod even though it should be a classmethod
        return super(MyMatrix, cls).__new__(cls, "1 2; 3 4")

mat = MyMatrix()

print mat
# outputs [[1 2] [3 4]]
```

---

Addendum: you might want to consider using a factory function, rather than a subclass, for the behaviour you want. This would give you the following code, which is much shorter and clearer, and doesn't depend on the `__new__`-vs-`__init__` implementation detail:

```
def mymatrix():
    return np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')

mat = mymatrix()
print mat
# outputs [[1 2] [3 4]]
```

Of course, you might need a subclass for other reasons.

Comment: @burga I've added a paragraph with an alternative version of the answer, which I consider better. Also, would you consider marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: good hint. but, the reason for implementing a subclass is that my implementation should have some additional attributes, e.g. a name for every matrix column/row.

Comment: @burga: Numpy's [`dtype`s](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes) already provide a facility for accessing data by name rather than by index.